# LINQ, Use Lambda Expression in Include Function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

My question looks simple to me but not getting it fixed. I am using EF 6 and LINQ to SQL in Visual Studio 2013. I want to fetch a record from second table on behalf of foreign key being used in first table. 
I wanted to use 'Include' function but 'Include' function neither show table names
in IntelliSense nor accepts in a lambda expression like this:

var record= db.tblChild.Include(x=>x.tblParent)

My original code shows the libraries added.

[image]

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the problematic line.
What is the error? Hover over the lambda expression and tell us what the tooltip says.

Comment: `using System.Data.Entity;` is what you need to be able to reference the lamda version of `.Include`, so that should work. We need to see what the error it is giving you after you add the semi-colon.

Comment: My error is fixed. Actually I wasn't generating SubSource Property in ShipmentCharges Class. Generating that fixed the Issue. :)

Answer (score 5):

In order to use lambdas in Include you have to import the System.Data.Entity namespace (which you have) and also reference EntityFramework.dll which includes the necessary extension methods.

Comment: My error is fixed. Actually I wasn't generating SubSource Property in ShipmentCharges Class. Generating that fixed the Issue. :)

Comment: @IkramKhan Well, posting the error would have put us on the right path way faster. Either way, good to hear you've solved it.

Answer (score -1):

You only need to add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Into your Namespace.